# Many-to-many relationship between Django User, Permissions, and another entity

Tags: django

Consider a Django web app for CompanyXYZ that provides goods and services to many organizations.  Users of the app will be affiliated with one or more of those organizations, and have different roles (and be permitted access to different data) within each.  So, imagine a schema like this:

```
Users>---UserOrg----<Org
             V
             |
          UserOrgPermissions
             |
             ^
           Permissions
```

Permissions relate to services provided by the company, and in general look like:  “Can order X”, “Can view X orders”, “Can order Y”, “Can view Y orders”, “Can order Z”...etc.  Users should be able to log on to CompanyXYZ’s site once, and then choose from among his/her affiliated organizations to view summary data and/or place orders, depending on his/her permissions at a given organization.

From an admin perspective, I need to be able to create organizations, create users, assign users to organizations, and assign permissions to users for each of his/her organizations.

I’m fairly new to Django, so I'm not sure if this is even doable. How would I start?

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like this:

```py
class Permission(models.Model):
    pass

class Org(models.Model):
    pass

class UserOrg(models.Model):
    org = models.Foreignkey('Org')
    user = models.Foreignkey('User')
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission)

class User(models.Model):
    orgs = models.ManyToManyField(Org, through=UserOrg)
```

I suggest you to either read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related) or start with their [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) for beginners.

Comment: Thanks.  I've read the docs and gone through several tutorials, but I'm still not clear on how to handle multiple many-to-many relationships.  Specifically, how to create the 'UserOrgPermissions' table, and how to access it from admin to apply permissions per user, per organization.

Comment: That's a quicky, answers the questions just right! But with all modesty, I would suggest to [derive User from AbstractUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)

Answer (score 0):

Django provides you almost all for you needs. Try to learn about users first. Avoid to create users from scrach, you can simple [use or customize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) the Django User models. then, [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#permission-model) and organizations can be solved with [groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.Group).